# Generating file throws error: Unexpected token '&'

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nuxt.js, script-tag

In a Nuxt project the files are compiled strangely. This leads to error messages in the console and in my case affects the tracking.

The following Console.log error message comes up:
`"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'".`

That is the part which occurs the console error:

```js
<script data-n-head="1" data-hid="tealium" type="text/javascript">
        (function(a,b,c,d){a=&#x27;//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/tr //etc... </script>
```

I expect: `a='//tags.tiqcdn...`

**The relevant nuxt.config.js part**

```js
{
    hid: `tealium
    innerHTML: `
      (function(a,b,c,d){a='//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/../utag.js';b=document;c='script';d=b. createElement(c);d.src=a;d.type='text/java'+c;d.async=true;a=b.getElementsByTagName(c)[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(d,a);})();
    `,
```

I use to build node v16.14.0 and npm 8.3.1.

**What I have already tried:**
I add **nuxt-charset-module**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-charset-module to push the
`<meta charset>` to first of `<head>`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `a="&#x27;"`? This is just a syntax error. `&#x27;` is a single quote, so your template string gets masked. You should insert that minified script some other way.

Comment: Hey @ChrisG it should: `{a='//tags. ...' ` the build process render my Apostrophe to &#x27;.

Comment: Something is wrong with the build process. Neither should `'` be rendered as `&#x27;` in html content in general (at best, it should be in attributes that are delimited by `'`) nor should anything be html-entity-escaped in `<script>` contents at all. This is not a charset problem.

Comment: @Bergi — As XSS filters go, escaping `'` is not a bad default (it is much safer than trying to detect if the content is inserted into a single quote delimited attribute value)

Comment: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/452

Comment: @Quentin you link is the good! Adding this `__dangerouslyDisableSanitizers: ['script']` to the nuxt.config.js file solved. Thank you and Bergi also ChrisG for the good and right hints!